# Dumping the contents of a multi-dimension array into a new JSON variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimension array that looks like this:

```
products = '[["A","Apple","20","apple.html"],["B","Banana","13","banana.html"],["C","Cereal","45","cereal.html"],["D","Dishes","320","dishes.html"]]';
```

I'm trying to turn this into a JSON object (at least I think that's what the format is), but only indexes 1 and 3... so products[0][1],products[0][3]. This what my results need to look like.

```
pList = [{value: 'Apple', data: 'apple.html'},{value: 'Banana', data: 'banana.html'}];
```

How do I go about getting this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Parse the string to an array by `JSON.parse`.
2. Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the values from the array.

```js
var products = '[["A","Apple","20","apple.html"],["B","Banana","13","banana.html"],["C","Cereal","45","cereal.html"],["D","Dishes","320","dishes.html"]]';

products = JSON.parse(products);

var pList = products.map(function(item) {
  return {
    value: item[1],
    data: item[3]
  };
});

console.log(pList);
```

Comment: That is so awesome!!! Just wondering... is the pList format i'm looking for JSON?

Comment: No, it's just an array with those value, you can use `plist = JSON.stringify(plist)` to convert it to JSON if you want.